# Possible to keep `Unit` as the return type of a Kotlin function when called from Java?

Tags: kotlin

I have a kotlin function inside a sealed class.

```
fun invoke(callback: Callback): Unit
```

Java sees the method signature as a function that returns `void`.

Is it possible to instruct the Kotlin compiler to keep `Unit` as the return type for Java? (not `void`)

## Use case

My use case is a jvm interop issue from Java where I need to implement `(Result) -> Unit`.

```
// inside a java method (currently)
abstractClass.invoke(callback)
return Unit.INSTANCE

// what I'd prefer instead
return abstractClass.invoke(callback) // invoke returns Unit, but it's in Kotlin, so it maps to void in Java. So this doesn't work
```

Comment: But Java doesn't have notion of `Unit`.

Comment: What would be your use case for this?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Yes it does - you can execute `System.out.println(kotlin.Unit.class);` from Java code.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I meant, in the language. `void` _is_ java's `Unit`. But you're right, of course.

Comment: @zsmb13 added my use case to question

Answer (score 2):

For your edge case, you'd still have to deal with Java methods returning `void`. So just solve it once:

```
fun <T> fromConsumer(consumer: Consumer<T>): (T) -> Unit = { consumer.consume(it) }
```

and then instead of implementing `(Result) -> Unit` directly, implement/create a `Consumer<Result>` and pass it to this function. It could be written in Java as well, just would be more complicated.

Comment: this looks like it will work! will try it and report back

Answer (score 0):

It would certainly be possible to do this in Java:

```
public kotlin.Unit test() { return null; }
```

But in Kotlin your best option seems to be to go with a function object:

```
val invoke: (Callback) -> Unit = {}

// from Java:
return abstractClass.getInvoke(callback)
```

Answer (score -2):

I may have misunderstood your question.

First, in Kotlin,

```
fun invoke(callback: Callback): Unit
```

is equivalent to

```
fun invoke(callback: Callback)
```

In Java, if you override a function like that, you do not need to return anything.

> Is it possible to instruct the Kotlin compiler to keep `Unit` as the return type for Java? (not `void`)

No, because `Unit` is meaningless. The only valid value of `Unit` is `Unit` itself.

Comment: `Unit is meaningless` - what would that mean?

Comment: @voddan I mean return `Unit` is meaningless. There is only **ONE** instance of `Unit`. It cannot be created or subclass. Just like `Void` in Java, you cannot create a `Void`. You can only return `null`.

Comment: but you can return `Unit.INSTANCE`. Or accept `Unit` as a parameter. Or put it into `List<Unit>`. It is just a final class with a private constructor ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Joshua "There is only ONE instance of Unit. It cannot be created or subclass." This applies to all `object`s. Do you think they are meaningless too?

Comment: @voddan Yes, you can do that but Kotlin does not intend to let users to use `Unit`. It is a internal class for void function mapping.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov "This applies to all objects." This statement is false as it does not apply to all objects. Singleton object has its own usage but `Unit` is not design for you to use. All its does it let Kotlin maps void function in Java.

Comment: @Joshua "There is only one instance of `Foo`. It cannot be created or subclassed. The only valid value of `Foo` is `Foo` itself." All of these statements are correct for any `object Foo`. So if they mean `Unit` is meaningless, they also mean `Foo` is meaningless.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Your statement is true if and only if `Foo` is a final class with private constructor and only has a one instance.Are all objects a final class with private constructor and only has a one instance? No, therefore you statement is false. Second, I said "return `Unit`" is meaningless because it is always the same value. Third, meaningless does not equal useless. `if (true)` is meaningless because it is always true.

Comment: @Joshua 1. I was talking about `object`s (as in the Kotlin keyword), not all objects. 2. Your answer says `Unit` is meaningless, not returning it. 3. `if (true)` has a very simple meaning, not no meaning.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov 1. `object` is a special term in OOP. For you meaning "Kotlin object" is called `companion object`. It is a singleton and can use for static replacement  in Java which is different from Unit. 2. See my first reply to voddan. 3. "meaningless" means "without meaning, significance, **purpose**, or value; purposeless; insignificant:" (from dictionary.com). It does not always mean no meaning. `if(true)` will always run,  therefore  that `if` serves no purpose. Many compilers will remove it in bytecode because it is meaningless. In Kotlin, return `Unit` is meaningless.

Comment: No, the OOP term is object. Just as `class` the keyword is not the same as class the term and not the same as `Class<T>`. And of course not all `object`s are `companion object`s: `Unit` is an example.

Comment: @Joshua I see that this thread turned into a word fight, which is unfortunate. Simply put, your statements like "Kotlin does not intend to let users to use Unit" are misleading and generally false. Kotlin uses `Unit` to resolve complex generic cases or as a default return object. For an example see functions like `runBlocking<Unit>`